# Sum the results of two function calls SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I would like to efficiently sum the results of two function calls and display the value in a third column.  Here is the syntax I have...

```
SELECT TOP (1000) Region, 
dbo.fn_Function1(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Students], 
dbo.fn_Function2(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Schools],
dbo.fn_Function3(Code, 2016) AS [Average Students],
dbo.fn_Function4(Code, 2016) AS [Average Schools], 
dbo.fn_Calculator(0,0) as [Total Students], 
dbo.fn_Calculator(0,0) as [Total Schools]
From myTable
```

fn_calculator is supposed to take as parameters the values of (Highest Students + Average Students) and Sum them.  Likewise for the (Highest Schools + Average Schools)

I would rather not re-run the functions again inside the parameters for the calculator function.  I just have (0,0) now as placeholder.  I tried to load the calculator like this:  But it does not recognize the column names:

```
dbo.fn_Calculator([Highest Students], [Average Students])
```

Comment: The  most efficient way is to avoid the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  most efficient way is to avoid the functions. But you could use a sub-query or CTE:

```
WITH Calcs AS
(
   SELECT Region, 
    dbo.fn_Function1(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Students], 
    dbo.fn_Function2(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Schools],
    dbo.fn_Function3(Code, 2016) AS [Average Students],
    dbo.fn_Function4(Code, 2016) AS [Average Schools], 
    From myTable
)
SELECT TOP 1000 
     [Highest Students],
     [Highest Schools],
     [Average Students],
     [Average Schools],
    dbo.fn_Calculator([Highest Students], [Average Students]) as [Total Students], 
    dbo.fn_Calculator([Highest Schools], [Average Schools]) as [Total Schools]
FROM Calcs
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution.  Fortunately the query needs to be run only a few times per year but is across millions of students.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
select top (1000)
    Region, 
    calc.[Highest Students], 
    calc.[Highest Schools],
    calc.[Average Students],
    calc.[Average Schools], 
    dbo.fn_Calculator(calc.[Highest Students], calc.[Average Students]) as [Total Students], 
    dbo.fn_Calculator(calc.[Highest Schools], calc.[Average Schools]) as [Total Schools]
From myTable as t
    outer apply (select
        dbo.fn_Function1(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Students], 
        dbo.fn_Function2(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Schools],
        dbo.fn_Function3(Code, 2016) AS [Average Students],
        dbo.fn_Function4(Code, 2016) AS [Average Schools]
    ) as calc
```

But in general, @TimSchmelter is quite correct about avoid using function if it's possible - scalar functions usually quite bad for performance. In your case, you could at least remove `fn_calculator` function:

```
select top (1000)
    Region, 
    calc.[Highest Students], 
    calc.[Highest Schools],
    calc.[Average Students],
    calc.[Average Schools], 
    calc.[Highest Students] + calc.[Average Students] as [Total Students], 
    calc.[Highest Schools] + calc.[Average Schools] as [Total Schools]
From myTable as t
    outer apply (select
        dbo.fn_Function1(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Students], 
        dbo.fn_Function2(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Schools],
        dbo.fn_Function3(Code, 2016) AS [Average Students],
        dbo.fn_Function4(Code, 2016) AS [Average Schools]
    ) as calc
```

You can also use a cte:

```
;with cte as (
    select top (1000)
        t.Region,
        dbo.fn_Function1(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Students], 
        dbo.fn_Function2(Code, 2016) AS [Highest Schools],
        dbo.fn_Function3(Code, 2016) AS [Average Students],
        dbo.fn_Function4(Code, 2016) AS [Average Schools]
    From myTable as t   
)
select
     c.Region,
     c.[Highest Students], 
     c.[Highest Schools],
     c.[Average Students],
     c.[Average Schools], 
     dbo.fn_Calculator(c.[Highest Students], c.[Average Students]) as [Total Students], 
     dbo.fn_Calculator(c.[Highest Schools], c.[Average Schools]) as [Total Schools]
from cte as c
```

Comment: FYI - The first example using the calculator DOES work, however the second example didn't add the numbers instead it appended them together.

Comment: @user2055729 then I can assume that your functions `fn_FunctionX` return strings instead of numbers